# CORS Issue with socket.io in production (MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, cors, mean

I am using socket.io and it works fine in development. I am using the MEAN Stack and in development the socket connection is setup like this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
   cors: {
      origins: ['http://localhost:4200'],
   },
});
```

which works fine.

In production though it does not work.
I'm using Nginx with reverse proxy to serve my node.js server and my angular application.

I changed the settings to this

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
   cors: {
      origin: 'http://travelinked.vm.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de',
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
      credentials: true      
   }
});
```

but it still does not work.

Here is my Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name http://travelinked.vm.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }    

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://141.62.65.110:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

   location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
  }
}
```

So my website is available on this website: http://travelinked.vm.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/
And my backend: http://travelinked.vm.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/api

Everything works except for the socket.io.
Always get this problem here

[image]

The issue is that the link is wrong.. the `api` is missing.
It should be like this `http://141.62.65.110/api/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nbwq82Z` but how can I add this??

EDIT:

For my frontend I have this BASE_URL which is the link to my endpoints in the backend

`static readonly BASE_URL: string = 'http://141.62.65.110/api';`

Here is the socket.io connection on my client

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
   private socket = io(`${ApiURLStore.BASE_URL}/`, { path: '/api' });
...
```

EDIT2:
Seems socket.io make a connection but with the wrong URL.
Here is a result of the network

[image]

So basically it connects to this connection?
http://141.62.65.110/api/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nbxuxae

The correct one should be like this I think:
http://141.62.65.110:3000/api/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nbxuxae

Do I have to change the link in the frontend?
Into like this:
`private socket = io('http://141.62.65.110:3000/', { path: '/api/socket.io' });`

Comment: /api in origin  might be a problem

Comment: I removed the /api in origin, still not working.. I think it is something with my reverse proxy

Comment: You are mixing domain names and IP addresses. For the browser (and CORS), these are different domains.

Comment: So I should change origin to http://141.62.65.110 ? Still got the problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/socket.io` which is usually located in node root is blocked by the CORS. You need to specify the CORS policy for it inside the nginx server block. This should do the trick

```
location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
  }
```

EDIT: also you have `rewrite` directive inside your `/api` block which omits the `/api/` from url

EDIT2: specify socket.io in require()

```
const io = require("socket.io")({
  path: "/api",
  ...
```

Comment: Hey thank you, but still not help.. what do you mean with rewriting directive?

Comment: This part `rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;` try removing it temporarily and check if socket.io url works then

Comment: If that doesn't help, update your question with the how you included socket.io on the frontend (something like this `<script src="/api/socket.io.js"></script>`)

Comment: I updated my post and added how I include socket.io on the frontend

Comment: in your express code  remove `/api` part 
as per documentation `For example if you set it to "http://example.com" only requests from "http://example.com" will be allowed.`

Comment: you will probably also need to specify a path to `/api/` https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html

Comment: I added that now in the frontend (updated my post) Seems there is no error anymore in the console. But there is no connection yet (cannot send any messages). I'm trying to figure out why now.. do you have any idea?

Comment: For further debugging try checking the network tab of the inspect element, and also logs (both nodejs and server) if you see something suspicious update the question and we can check go from there

Comment: Thanks for the info! I realize the socket.io connects to the wrong url. I updated my post again. Meanwhile I try to change my path in the frontend.. hope it works